# Crop image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, crop

I've created a two-column grid of images, which works fine with all-landscape images: [Link](http://www.mtscollective.com/2014/03/gallery-wonder-years-real-friends-and.html). However, I've added a portrait image that throws off the layout, so I'd like to be able to "crop" the image so that the height matches the others'. [I tried using a negative margin](http://cssglobe.com/3-easy-and-fast-css-techniques-for-faux-image/), but it had no effect:

```css
.portrait-crop
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

img.portrait-crop
{
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

For reference, [this is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/91z2wxfy/).

Comment: your selector are bad. use `.protrait-crop img` intead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put some height to the container also, if not, it doesn't know how much it should show of what it is inside.

You can try something like this.

```css
.portrait-crop{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 215px;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.portrait-crop img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hmm not sure why, but this shrinks the image to fit vertically, but then becomes too narrow and doesn't crop.

Comment: the `width: 100%` is **scaling** the `img` down to the width of `.portrait-crop` (its parent element)

Answer (score 16):

You can crop images like this:

CSS:

```css
.crop-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.crop-container img {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Adjust the `height` and `width` of the container to adjust the dimensions of the cropped image and adjust the amount of negative `margin-top` and `margin-left` on the image element itself to choose which part of the image to crop to.

HTML:

```html
<div class="crop-container">
    <img src="some-img"/>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcezd2x6/14/)**

[image]

Alternative solution for a 2 column grid with fixed height rows:

CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
div.img {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    margin: 0.5%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover!important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
}
div.row {
    height: 300px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class='row'>
    <div class='img' style='background: url("some-image");'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class='img' style='background: url("some-other-image");'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='img' style='background: url("foo-image");'>&nbsp;</div>
    <div class='img' style='background: url("bar-image");'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/La64o9dr/1/)**

Comment: I tried this and the results are quite odd; the image is resized and centred in the space that the others use. Not sure why.

Comment: You will still need to specify the dimensions to scale your original images down to. You will also need to give the `.crop-container` element the CSS: `display: inline-block;` if you want a grid type layout of images.

Comment: I don't really get it, but thanks. I'll have to keep playing with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can crop from the top, bottom, left and right using 4 CSS properties:

- `object-fit`
- `object-position`
- `width`
- `height`

```css
#crop-bottom {
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
}

#crop-top {
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: bottom;
}
#crop-left {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: right;
}
#crop-right {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: left;
}
```

```html
<img id="no-crop" src="https://satyr.dev/350x150">
no-crop
<br />
<img id="crop-bottom" src="https://satyr.dev/350x150">
crop the bottom of the image
<br />
<img id="crop-top" src="https://satyr.dev/350x150">
crop the top of the image
<br />
<img id="crop-left" src="https://satyr.dev/350x150">
crop the left of the image
<br />
<img id="crop-right" src="https://satyr.dev/350x150">
crop the right of the image
```

Comment: Easiest answer for modern browsers, but it looks like the images in the snippet aren't appearing for some reason.

Comment: thx @GarrettAlbright, SO was blocking placeholder.com because reasons ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS3 to handle this very elegantly in a single div without any extra containers :

```css
.portrait-crop {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="portrait-crop" style="background: url(https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png);"></div>
```

Comment: Problem is that my image src needs to match the href to trigger the website's lightbox.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that. It seems the site is not really using current stuff, so the triggers are wrapped up requireing <a> and  <img> tags.  I did notice you are using jQuery, so perhaps using some wizardry to apply this technique after page load might be a decent option. I don't have the time necessary to work with the layout. You could also try applying the light-box photo box to the div, usually you can use rel="foo", then href="somephoto" and it would grab the href as the image src, while still being able to apply style="" for the background.

Comment: The problem with negative margins is that they are outdated and vary from browser to browser, where CSS background is pretty much fully implemented and consistent at this point :  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp  .  I recently had a similar problem I needed to solve in a project I am currently working on, which is why the CSS solution was fresh in my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Your problem is on CSS selectors.

```css
img.portrait-crop
{
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

matches an image with portrait-crop class.

but this

```css
.portrait-crop img
{
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

Matches an image inside a protrait-crop container.

Answer (score 1):

Crop Image in CSS

```css
.crop{      
    clip-path: inset(40px 0 0 0); //for left side                                            
    clip-path: inset(0 40px 0 0); // for top side                              
    clip-path: inset(0 0 40px 0); // for right side                            
    clip-path: inset(0 0 0 40px); // for bottom side                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this CSS:

```css
img { height: 280px; }
.portrait-crop { height: 560px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/91z2wxfy/2/

Comment: On his actual site it would need to be .portrait-crop { height: 431px; } for this to work at his widest layout.
But then there are ratio issues with the width and height without making major changes to the layout.

Comment: That will not **crop** anything only squash/stretch images which quite frankly looks worse than the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, using only css without affecting your html code is this:

```css
/* Fix for portrait */
.portrait-crop {
     width:50%;
     overflow:hidden;
     height:179px;
     display:inline-block;
 }
 .portrait-crop img {
       width:100%;
       height:auto;
 }
```

or, adding some div (better solution): http://jsfiddle.net/yoyb9jn7/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Surround the img tag in a dive with a overflow wit fixed width and height and apply a width or height depending on its orientation
Try this out

```css
.overflow{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 271px;   
 }

.overflow img{
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/91z2wxfy/9/