# Having trouble manipulating image size + bootstrap

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey guys I'm at a bit of a loss here.

I'm trying to recreate this web page:
[image: reference image]

Here's what my result looks like: 
[image: my work]

I'm having trouble with the image.  I've got it pretty well where I'd like it but I can't seem to get the height to match the reference image.  I figured it would fit nicely into a bootstrap row without needing much css.

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <h1>Lorem </br> Ipsumsz</h1> </br> <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet consecetur adipised do </br>           elusmod tempor incididunt. Adipised do eiusmod tempor.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <h1 id="bigNumber">01</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-4">
     <img src="olu-eletu-27968.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap rows have no inherent height. They'll expand to fit whatever you put in them. So, you'll need to set a `height` or `max-height` CSS property on your `.row`.

The other trick is that you want to display the image with a different crop and aspect ratio than its natural state. In other words, you don't want to display the full image, just part of it. [You can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218954/crop-image-in-css) with a combination of `<img>` with a `<div>`, but it feels kind of hacky because you have to use negative margins. I think it's easier to make the image a `background-image` [using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Try something like this:

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Lorem <br> Ipsumsz</h1> <br> <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet consecetur adipised do <br>           elusmod tempor incididunt. Adipised do eiusmod tempor.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1 id="bigNumber">01</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height: 300px;">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-4" style="background-image: url('olu-eletu-27968.jpg'); background-position: center;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS. Your `</br>` tags should just be `<br>`. `' is an invalid tag and will most likely be ignored by your browser.